# MongoDb like query with sort performance

Tags: regex, mongodb, performance, sorting, aggregation-framework

i am using mongodb 3.6 in which i have Usermst collection which have users documents. I am going to fetch user first name & last name who did more posts. Below is my mongodb query.

```
    db.getCollection("UserMst").aggregate([
    {$match :{$and:[{os : {$in:[0,1]}}, {_id : {$nin : [3,10]}}]}}
    ,{$match:{$and:
         [ {$or: [
           {$and : [{fname:{$regex : `^has.*` , $options: 'i' }},{lname:{$regex : `^pa.*` , $options: 'i' }}]}  
          ,{$and:  [{fname:{$regex : `^pa.*` , $options: 'i' }}, {lname:{$regex : `^has.*` , $options: 'i' }}]}
          ]}
         ]
         }
    }
    ,{$sort:{'posts':-1,'_id':-1}}
    ,{$project:{"fname":1,"lname":1,"posts":1}}
    ,{$limit:5}
    ])
```

I have index  "name" : "os_1_posts_-1". This query is time consuming.Is there any way to optimize query ?

Comment: Is `posts` an array?

Comment: can you provide sample of documents?

Comment: @willis, No posts have integer values.

Comment: @matthPen below is sample document.
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(8596321), 
    "fname" : "Harth", 
    "lname" : "jose", 
    "imgpath" : "", 
    "imgname" : "", 
    "status" : "A", 
    "posts" : 7.0, 
    "os" : 1.0
}

Answer (score 0):

1. If you take a look at your match: `{$match :{$and:[{os : {$in:[0,1]}}, {_id : {$nin : [3,10]}}]}}` you can see that you're trying to match on `os` and `_id` -- if you're trying to match on _id, you'll often want to have `_id` in your index.
2. In the next $match, you're trying to do a match on `fname` OR `lname` -- this is slow if not indexed (and ORs in general are hard to index). This seems like it might be the part of the query with the highest cardinality.
3. You're not actually using any aggregation specific features in this pipeline! You could instead write this as a regular query and use projection and limit. You're also using `$and` in places where you don't need it

Your aggregation pipeline's query looks something like:

```
{
  os: {$in: [0, 1] },
  _id : {$nin : [3,10]},
  $or: [
    {
      fname: { $regex: `^has.*` , $options: 'i' },
      lname:{ $regex: `^pa.*` , $options: 'i' }
    },
    {
      fname: {$regex : `^pa.*` , $options: 'i' },
      lname:{$regex : `^has.*` , $options: 'i' 
    }
  ]
}
```

And then sorts on `posts` and then `_id`

I'm unsure about which fields have the highest cardinality, what your data looks like, & what other queries you're running on this database, so it's very hard to recommend an actual index, but a compound index that looks something like `{lname, fname, os, posts, _id}` should perform better.